# Moved/Replaced outlet, now it's not working

Tags: electrical

I (or someone doing work in my house) recently moved a 3-prong outlet up a few inches and replaced the receptacle.

The outlet is connected to a switch and is the end of the line on the circuit. 
Using a non-contact tester, I get a reading from the wires in the box (not if I use the outlet holes). They give a reading when the switch is on, and no reading when it was off, just as you would expect.

I checked the connections and looked fine, I tried using another outlet in case the one I had was bad. Still no go. Any ideas what could be going on?

Note: There is only a 2-wire cable going into the box (black/white - no ground). I know I need to use a GFCI and/or label it (already a GFCI earlier in the circuit).

Comment: That was a lot of writing for an outlet swap. You might want to pare it down to the essentials to save your volunteer helpers some time. Backstory is really not important. The bottom line is that there's a bad/missing connection somewhere. How did you extend the wiring from the original box location?

Comment: Did you check if either of the tabs was broken off between the two  screws?

Comment: @isherwood The wire came into the old box from above, so moving the box to a higher position still provided easy access to that wire.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose I did not.  Would that matter in this case?  Neither the top or bottom is providing power.

Comment: Yes, if both tabs are broken off and the hot wire  is on the top screw and the neutral is on the bottom screw (or vice versa) then neither the top or bottom will work.

Comment: Ah, well I am not sure on the tab (don't believe it was removed), but know the black and white are both attached at the top.

Comment: If there was something wrong with the neutral, a non-contact tester would behave the way you describe, but there would be not usable voltage at the outlet.

Comment: I've called an electrician.  I fear something has come loose/broken in the wall/ceiling, but I don't know.  I don't really want to start cutting holes as new drywall was just put up.  I'm especially leary of cutting holes in the ceiling because it has a texture.

I can easily add a new circuit on the other side of the room, but that would be the least likely spot someone would need a outlet in the room (The current outlet is the only outlet).

Comment: If neutral is giving you a voltage-detect reading when the switch is on, then the neutral is faulty at an upstream location.

Comment: Turns out something must have been loose on the circuit.  The GFCI I thought was earlier in the circuit was in fact not, it splits off from another outlet somewhere and is an end of it's line.  The GFCI was however a little loose on the connections.

The electrician pulled all the outlets and switches out of the boxes and examined them, and now the problem outlet works.  If I had to guess it was the GFCI causing a short perhaps?